# Json Array in Powershell from Podto Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, ansible, ansible-tower, invoke-restmethod

I have the following Json in the body of a Postman. what would be equivalent code in Powershell to send rest API via invoke-webrequest or via invoke-restmethod?

Postman Body:

```
{
    "extra_vars": {
        "servername": "apicall1234",
        "servers": "server01,server02,server06,server-12345"
    }
}
```

Comment: The equivalent code of what? What have you tried so far to solve your requirement. Please have a read of our [ask] page

Comment: sorry about that, still learning stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a request body via the `-Body` parameter on either of the web cmdlets. As with Postman (or any other HTTP client), you'll need to provide an address and a method/verb.

```
$uri = 'https://<url goes here>/path'
$reqBody = '{ "extra_vars": { "servername": "apicall1234", "servers": "server01,server02,server06,server-12345" } }'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Body $reqBody -Method Post
```